# Issue using two seperate scripts in a html file

Tags: javascript

Running separate scripts throughout my page. I have the first running, but my second, separate, script will not populate.

First:

```
<input id="barbwire" class="input-pricing" type="number" 
    oninput="barbwirePricing()">Length
<span id="barbwireMetal"></span>

<script>
    function barbwirePricing() {
        var length = document.getElementById("barbwire").value;
        var metal = (((lenght / 100) + 9) * 8 * 1.5) * 1.1;

    document.getElementById("barbwireMetal").innerHTML = "2 3/8 Drill Pipe: $" 
        + metal.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

But when I later try to use a similar formatting it wont populate oninput.

```
<input id="privacy" class="input-pricing" type="number" 
    oninput="privacyPricing()">Length
<span id="privacyMetal"></span>

<script>
    function privacyPricing() {
        var length = document.getElementById("privacy").value;
        var metal = ((length / 8) + 2) * 8 * 1.5 * 1.1;

    document.getElementById("privacyMetal").innerHTML = "2 3/8 Drill Pipe: $" 
        + metal.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Given that your variable `length` is of type `string`, you might want to convert it to a `number` before using it in your calculations. Even if your `input` contains a `number`, the returned value is of type `string`. E.g. do `parseInt(document.getElementById("privacy").value)`

Comment: You are missing some `}`

Comment: Hey @Jeffrey. Where do these functions end? Cant see } on either one. Also, where are you calling the functions (on the page loading up? On a button click?)

Comment: @LGSon It doesn't matter in this case, JS will do the cast itself.
@Chris OP calls them in his `input`s

Comment: @SergeK. It might, still, good practice to do it and make _sure_ it works.

Comment: sorry pulling from a larger document and piecing together, each section ends with a }

Comment: the functions are oninput

Comment: @Jeffrey look at you console.

Comment: As you existing snippets actually works, and for us to be able to help, we need a [mcve], and note, external links is not good enough, the issue needs to be reproduced within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the result you see is the latter, **the former isn't display correctly**.

There was a typo in your first script.

`var metal = (((lenght / 100) + 9) * 8 * 1.5) * 1.1;`

here, `lenght` is not defined.

Use [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to debug will help a lot.

Hope it makes your day.